# How to SETNOCOUNTOFF from the sql query

Tags: asp.net, sql, select

i have a select staement which i use ExecuteNonQuery() property of SQL to return the number of affected rows. However this returns -1 all the times. I did research and realized its a result of SETNOCOUN ON property of SQL. Pls how do i off it from the query as i am not using stored procedure? Below is my code.

```
protected void txtName_Changed(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string sql = "";

            using (SqlCommand cmd = connection.CreateCommand())
            {
                sql = "SET NOCOUNT OFF;SELECT * FROM [CLIENT] WHERE cname = '" + txtName.Text + "'";
                cmd.Connection = connection;
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                cmd.CommandText = sql;
                connection.Open();
                int i = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                if (i > 0 )
                {
                    txtName.BackColor = System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.FromHtml("#FD5E53");
                    txtName.BorderColor = System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.FromHtml("#CD4A4A");

                    lblError.Text = "Client Exist.";
                    lblError.Visible = true;
                    lblError.Enabled = true;
                    btnInsertClient.Enabled = false;
                    pnlAddEdit_ModalPopupExtender.Show();
                    //    return;
                }
                else
                {
                    txtName.BackColor = System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.FromHtml("#F2F0E1");
                    txtName.BorderColor = System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.FromHtml("#FFFFFF");

                    lblError.Text = "";
                    lblError.Visible = false;
                    lblError.Enabled = false;
                    btnInsertClient.Enabled = true;
                    pnlAddEdit_ModalPopupExtender.Show();
                }
                connection.Close();

            }
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use [`Execute**Non**Query()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executenonquery.aspx):

> For **UPDATE, INSERT, and DELETE** statements, the return value is the number of rows affected by the command. When a trigger exists on a table being inserted or updated, the return value includes the number of rows affected by both the insert or update operation and the number of rows affected by the trigger or triggers. **For all other types of statements, the return value is -1.** If a rollback occurs, the return value is also -1.

Try [`ExecuteScalar()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executescalar.aspx) for example:

> Executes the query, and returns the first column of the first row in the result set returned by the query.

Then make your query a `COUNT()`.

Oh, and watch out for SQL injection and repetitive code.

Comment: Thank you man. However when i use the executescalar i saw it returns a number that is beyond reasoning. I am kindd of confused . What does it actually returns when cast to an int?

Comment: It returns _"the first column of the first row in the result set returned by the query"_.